# Can't leave focus on same cell in DataGridView in CellValueChanged handler (.NET)

Tags: winforms, datagridview

In the event handler for CellValueChanged, for a certain condition, I want the focus to stay in the cell and clear its content. What's happening is focus (cursor) is in the next cell when the handler finishes its work. It needs to be in the same cell that caused the event.

```
MyGrid.CellValueChanged -= new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(CellValueChanged);
if (condition)
{
MyGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnName"].Value = "";
MyGrid.CurrentCell = MyGrid["ColumnName", e.RowIndex];
MyGrid.BeginEdit(true);
return;
}
```

....

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for CellValidating event instead value changed event. Put that conditional code in this event and if that condition is failed then make e.Cancel = true, which will keep the focus in the same cell.